# AWS DynamoDB Scan Filter Expression Returning Empty

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm stumped trying to figure out why my scan won't return anything but [ ]. Here are my scan params:

```
var params = {
                TableName: tableName,
                FilterExpression: "#wager = :wager",
                ExpressionAttributeNames: {
                    "#wager": "wager"
                },
                ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                    ":wager": wager
                }
            };
```

My DynamoDB table works perfectly when I run a filter expression in the DynamoDB dashboard, like "wager [NUMBER] = 0.001".

Comment: Double check the type of variable `wager`

Comment: Are you sure your results aren't being paginated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the ideas everyone. it did indeed turn out to be a type issue - all I had to do was cast "wager" as

wager = Number(wager);

ahead of setting the scan params (the same params I have in the question worked).

Answer (score 1):

jellycsc and Seth Geoghegan already mentioned the two most likely explanations in comments:

First, make sure you do not call a single `Scan` operation, but rather do a *loop* to get all the *pages* of the scan result. The specific way to do this depends on which programing language you are using. When your filter leaves only a small subset of the results (e.g., only when wage is exactly 0.001) remember to read all the pages is critical, because the first page may be empty: DynamoDB might have read 1MB of items (the default page size), and **none** of them matched wager=0.001 so an empty first page is return.

Second, the `wager` might have a wrong type. Obviously, if you store numbers but search for a string, nothing would match, so check you didn't do that. But a more subtle problem can be how you store numbers. DynamoDB holds floating-point in an unusual manner - using decimal, not binary, digits. This means that DynamoDB can hold the number "0.001" precisely, without any rounding errors. The same cannot be said for most programming languages. On my machine, if I set a "double" variable to 0.001, the result is 0.0010000000000000000208. If I pass this to DynamoDB, the equality check will not match! This means you should make sure that `wager` variable is **not** a double. In Python, for example, `wager` should be set to `Decimal("0.001")` - note how it is constructed from the string "0.001", not from the floating-point 0.001 which already has rounding errors.